# designing XML with large data sets for ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a very large XML file which has like 40000 data, and when I try to load the XML using Actionscript3, and then populate the data into an Array,
I get the following Error:

A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds.

Is there a way to bypass this timeout issue?
Here is the sample XML

```
<Map>
   <Data>0</Data>
   <Data>1</Data>
   <Data>2</Data>
   <Data>3</Data>
    // continue for many many times
   <Data>39999</Data>
</Map>
```

The line break seems to be at the for loop.
The code is like this

```
var aNumberArray:Array = new Array( 200 * 200 );
var nRowIndex:int = 0;
for ( ; 200 > nRowIndex; ++nRowIndex ) {
    var nColumnIndex:int = 0;
    for ( ; 200 > nColumnIndex; ++nColumnIndex ) {
        var nIndex:int = nColumnIndex + nRowIndex * 200;
        // assume cXMLMap is already a pre read XML class
        aNumberArray[ nIndex ] = new int( cXMLMap.Data[ nIndex ] );
    }
}
```

I am suspecting that the `cXMLMap.Data[ nIndex ]` is taking alot of time to get the variable from the XML.
Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,
I need to change the format of the XML to something like below

```
// given a data set of 200 X 200 fields
<Map>
    <Data>00 10 20 30 40 ..... 1990</Data>
    <Data>00 11 21 31 41 ..... 1991</Data>
    // repeat until reach 200 times
    <Data>2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 ..... 199200</Data>
</Map>
```

This will reduce the XML parsing duration, however, I need to write code to tokenize the string in actionscript3.

Comment: Bear in mind as a matter of good practice that you should never be grabbing infeasibly large data sets from the server as you'll bog down both your server and your client. If it's possible, better that you should limit the response on the server side (which will help immunise your server against DOS attacks), then write your app to grab the data in bite-sized chunks. HTH.